# SharePoint Site Intranet Integration

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, intranet

**Scenario:**
I build a SharePoint site on a personal Dev Site hosted on my Office 365 online server, SharePoint Online. Client would like to host said site on their intranet so that their I.T. can manage employee authorization, retain privacy and overall manage internally.

**Question:**

1. Is it possible to move the SharePoint online hosted site to a SharePoint intranet server?
2. Are there any concerns that should be considered?
3. Any recommendations on project planning/plan of attack and execution?

Comment: Assuming the client is running SharePoint 2013. Yes. You can give them all the assets you have, they can spin up a site, apply the assets, and run what you've created.

Comment: @Eric Alexander So the version of SharePoint makes a big difference on Site Migration. A third party tool will still be used regardless, correct?

Comment: Yes, version matters. Most likely yes, you'll need a tool. It makes it easier. If they don't care about content, then you can just copy over design elements and start fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOTB method which will do backup and restore from SPO to on prem. Here are couple of ways to do.

1. Create new site collection in Intranet servers and apply your customization manually over there.
2. Use the 3rd party tool to move the site collection between the Office 365 and SharePoint on-prem. I would try Sharegate as they offer free trail.

Comment: Method 2 seems to be the best approach for seamless I.T. hand off but I'll also look at method 1. Thanks for the jumping off point.

Comment: main problem with the manual thing is version mismatch. In SharePoint Online we always have latest version which in many case not released to the on prem...so i try 1st one but i think option 2 is best

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

1. When you say move a site, it should come down to moving the data between the sites. You could possibly use third party migration tool like Sharegate which does a fantastic job in migrating all the content editor webparts and scripts within script editors of your pages. AFAIK, you can move to SP 2016 or SP 2013. So create a new site in Intranet and copy over the contents.
2. Concerns? Maybe the data volume for transfer? Check for taxonomy fields that you have. Also, user metadata would be different after export. i.e, a document's created by and created date fields. But this can also be managed within the tool. So keep an eye on those stuffs. Hope you have not implemented any SPFx web parts in your online env. Because this wont work onpremise at the moment.
3. Recommendation would be, for a PM, to evaluate external plugins or dependencies for the portal other than data within the site. I mean, user profile data, using public CDNs in master pages, taxonomy migration, add-in integration, etc. The lesser the customization, the easier it should be to migrate. Also plan to use a third party tool to copy over data. Believe me it will save a lot of time :)